# Traversing through all the records in Odoo scheduled action

Tags: python, odoo

I'm creating a cron job which will run every day and check for a specific field value from the record. Can you suggest me, how to traverse through all the records? There's an already available variable "records". Can I make use of this variable?

I've tried to traverse through the records field, I tried `task = env['x.duties']` but I'm not sure how to move forward.

**Edit:** 
I'm using Odoo 12 web edition. I have created a custom application named Task(Using odoo studio) where we define tasks for employees. Some of the tasks are supposed to be reoccurring. so I have defined condition for that, for example, the task can be reoccurring based on the number of days or based on any date of every month.

I need to create an automated action where I check if a task(a record) need to be created.  I am doing so from the web interface by selecting "Execute Python Code" under "action to do option". In code section i need to fetch all the record and then traverse through each of them to check if a new record needs to be created.

There are a number of pre-defined variables like env, record, records, etc. I need to know how to proceed.

I was able to create a new record using
 `env['x_duties'].create({'x_name': 'example'})`

Please guide me on how to fetch all the records of a particular model and traverse through the records one by one using a loop

Comment: Can you please get into more detail? Which Odoo version, what is the requirement in short and please add a simple but understandable example.

Comment: @CZoellner, I've added the details in the question. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `search()` of your model in the automated action code. For example to find every record in your database and create a new one after checking a condition:

```py
# search all duties in database
# probably use a better domain to filter out non interesting
# duties for example archived records
duties = env['x_duties'].search([])
for duty in duties:
    # does this duty meet the condition?
    if duty._meets_condition():  # implement your own way this is just pseudo!
        values = {'x_name': 'new duty as recurring for %s' % duty.x_name}
        duty.create(values)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll try and do as you suggested.